# M1 Mac: Accessing files from installed iOS apps to read/write

Tags: apple-silicon

I have an M1 Mac and I'm wondering if it's possible to read and write files that are used by installed iOS applications, specifically the files that the iOS application reads and writes (i.e. not read-only application data or resources). I'd specifically like to view and edit save files for iOS games I have installed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to `~/Library/Containers/` in Finder (note: this Library folder is hidden, so you either have to enable the option to show hidden items, or use Go → Go to folder ...). The subfolder has the name of the app (at least for one I developed years ago and just installed on my Mac):

[image]

Where the save files reside will depend on the application; they could be in Documents, in a Library subfolder or somewhere else.